# How to understand JS realms

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

In ECMAScript specification there is notion of "realms" introduced:

> Before it is evaluated, all ECMAScript code must be associated with a realm. Conceptually, a realm consists
>   of a set of intrinsic objects, an ECMAScript global environment, all of the ECMAScript code that is loaded
>   within the scope of that global environment, and other associated state and resources.

In Rauschmayer's book "Speaking JavaScript" author writes about objects which can cross realms:

> In web browsers, each frame and window has its own realm with separate global variables. That prevents instanceof from working for objects that cross realms.

What exactly constitutes "realm"? What else besides frame can separate websites code to another realm and what are the consequences?

Comment: Is there some particular issue you're facing or are you just trying to understand the concept?

Comment: I am trying to understand the concept. I found references to realms in different books about JS, but never any verbose description of this topic.

Comment: Other than inter-window function calls, which depending on your front-end architecture may or may not be something you have to worry about, the "realm" concept is really not something that comes up as a fundamental concept. A realm is the place where the global standard constructors like `Object` and `Array` "live".

Comment: @Pointy I think it's more important to state that every realm has its own "global" scope :-)

Comment: when searching for the use of `Array.isArray` on [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray#instanceof_vs._array.isarray), I found your explanation! Simple and easy to understand!

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The language reference uses abstract terms because JavaScript environments can vary widely. In the browser, a window (a frame, a window opened with `window.open()`, or just a plain browser tab) is a realm. A web worker is a different kind of realm than a window, but it's a realm. Same goes for service workers.

It's possible for an object to cross realm boundaries because windows opened from a common base window can intercommunicate via function calls and simple variable references. The mention of `instanceof` in that excerpt you quoted has to do with that. Consider this code in an `<iframe>` window:

```
window.parent.someFunction(["hello", "world"]);
```

Then imagine a function in the parent window:

```
function someFunction(arg) {
  if (arg instanceof Array) {
    // ... operate on the array
  }
}
```

That *won't work*.  Why?  Because the array constructed in the `<iframe>` window was constructed from the Array constructor in that realm, and therefore the array is *not* an instance constructed from the Array in the parent window.

There's a much stronger "wall" between web worker realms and window realms, and such effects don't happen in those interactions.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no proper explanation to what a realm in javascript is, I decided to come up with one myself. I promise you it'll answer all your questions around what realms are in javascript.

https://weizman.github.io/page-what-is-a-realm-in-js/

Here's the gist of it, although it's really hard summing realms up into a few sentences:

You can informally think of a realm as basically an ecosystem in which a JavaScript program lives. And just like any other ecosystem, it includes different elements that JavaScript programs must have in order to exist within it:

1. A global execution environment
2. A global object (and intrinsic objects)
3. JavaScript itself

There could be multiple realms in one program, and that would mean each realm will have a new and unique set of everything that is mentioned above.

This will effectively mean that two realms will both have some basic APIs provided by the execution environment, but they will be different instances of the same thing:

```js
window.fetch === some_iframe.contentWindow.fetch // false
window.Array === some_iframe.contentWindow.Array // false
window.Math.PI === some_iframe.contentWindow.Math.PI // true because 
primitive values (such as Number) are compared by their value
```

Realms in the browser are created in different scenarios, most common one is probably `<iframe>`.

Again, reading the post I wrote will help you understand this concept better.