# ESNext : Decorator. What is the `%PrivateNameSet%`?

Tags: javascript, specifications, ecmascript-next

[%PrivateNameSet%](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-decorators/#sec-private-name-set)

Spec said,

> `%PrivateNameSet%` is a per-realm built-in function object

what is the **per-realm built-in function object** ?
It's mean built-in function that `this` is already bind as global object?
So, `O` in `%PrivateNameSet%` is global object?

Comment: Which of the terms "per-realm", "built-in" and "function object" are you asking about exactly?

Comment: @Bergi *pre-realm*. I can't understand this

Comment: Actually that sentence seems to be pretty superfluous. `%PrivateName%.prototype.set` is - like any other method in the spec that isn't explicitly described otherwise  - a function object, built-into the implementation, and created per realm. It's very much the default.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/49832187/1048572

Comment: @Bergi Oh, So `O` in `%PrivateNameSet%` is global object?

Comment: @Bergi thank you :)
And I also read [this article](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/javascript-the-core-2nd-edition/#realm)  

It said  
>  A code realm is an object which encapsulates a separate global environment.  

Dose it right?

Comment: No, `O` is the `this` value in the method, the receiver of the call. It would usually be a %PrivateName% instance.

Comment: `%PrivateName% ` instance that created per realm?

Comment: The prototype object with all its methods is created once per realm