# How are realms created in the browser?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand in depth the concept of Javascript realms. However, I'm still having many problems with getting it correctly. First of all, I do not know how does the browser, lets say - Chrome, is able to create different JS realms for each tab. I'm looking for a deep explanation. Is there some API (JS API or Web API) for that excluding iframes? Or maybe it is something internal to V8?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49832187/how-to-understand-js-realms

Comment: I have read it already. It does not answer my questions.

Comment: I don't think realms are first-class objects, there's no API for them. It's just the way the JavaScript implementation keeps each execution context separate.