# When JS code from different sources (Scripts or Modules) must shares the same Realm object?

Tags: javascript, ecma

The ECMAScript [defines](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-code-realms) `realm` object as one that must be associated with JS code before evaluating. It holds references to the global object and global environment. Such specification entities as `Module Record` and `Script Record` have reference to its `realm` so their code would be running with this `realm`.

If we have a dependency graph of several modules (`Module Record`s) must all of them store the same `realm` object? It should be so in due to these modules have to share a single global environment but I can't draw the specific rule on it from the specification.

There is the following [instruction](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-global-environment-records):

> A global Environment Record is used to represent the outer most scope
> that is shared by all of the ECMAScript Script elements that are
> processed in a common realm.

albeit it restricts "a common realm" to `Script` elements (for reasons arcane for me).

So my final question is what's the conditions under which JS code from different sources must be executed with the same `realm` object (and then all this code shares the same global environment) and, oppositely, when JS code is eligible to create its own `realm`? (this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49832343/5006880) tells one of the cases is `<iframe>`).