# Is it possible several JavaScript realms share one single global object?

Tags: javascript

As [it is said](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-code-realms) in the ECMAScript spec, all JavaScript code must be associated with a `realm`. This spec entity, in turn, is related with the fabled global object. I have not found any prohibition on sharing a single global object between several realms.

So I wonder is it then possible, for example, to get `true` from the expression `arg instanceof Array` when `arg` was created within the scope of a different realm (I mean something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49832343/5006880), it's a sample with `<iframe>`).

Does not the ECMAScript guarantee that this sort of situations are unachievable?

Comment: Are you asking about sharing "only" the global object, or also sharing all the intrinsics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not explicitly forbidden, but imo it's pointless. You'd rather share the entire realm.

However, [§9.6 *InitializeHostDefinedRealm()*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-initializehostdefinedrealm) seems to suggest that every realm should have its own global object:

> 7. If the host requires use of an exotic object to serve as `realm`'s global object, let `global` be such an object **created** in a host-defined manner.
>
> <sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

But I'm probably reading too much into that. Also, I'm not quite sure if *InitializeHostDefinedRealm()* is the only entry point for a host that could be used to create a realm.

Comment: To recap, there are situations when `arg instanceof Array` might return true (providing that `arg` was created outside the scope of the current realm): a) several realms share the single global object; b) all ECMAScript code is associated with one single realm; c) appropriate fields of several global objects (global environments) is referenced to the single instance of `Array`. It seems none of these situations are explicitly prohibited by the spec.