# Why every execution context has Realm?

Tags: javascript, executioncontext

I'm reading ECMAScript 2023.
It say all execution contexts has "Realm" state component.

And it describes,

> a realm consists of a set of intrinsic objects, an ECMAScript global environment, all of the ECMAScript code that is loaded within the scope of that global environment, and other associated state and resources.

I understand realm is for global environment like window(browser), global(node).
And I understand "Global Environment Records" already define global environment once on first code evaluation.

I wonder why a Realm for a execution context is needed.

I'm reading https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-execution-contexts.

Comment: The global environment (record) does **not** contain the "*set of intrinsic objects, all of the ECMAScript code that is loaded within the scope of that global environment, and other associated state and resources*", so that's what the realm is needed for.

Comment: See also [How to understand JS realms?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49832187/1048572)

Comment: Can you clarify how this question relates to MongoDB Realm the database, per the tag on the question? Also, is this a specific programming question? Please review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Jay I wanted to ask "ECMAScript realm" but the tag "realm" point out MongoDB Realm. I didn't recognize that. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the [*current Realm record*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#current-realm) as "*the value of the Realm component of the [running execution context](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#running-execution-context)*".

That term is referenced multiple times across the specification, mostly for bookkeeping to carry-over the value, but in the end to lookup intrinsic prototypes or cached template strings from the current realm.